# Format a datagridview that's using npgsql

Tags: c#, postgresql, winforms, npgsql

I have a datagridviewer that loading data from a PostgreSQL database using npgSQL. However, I cannot seem to set properties such as column width when using it. This leaves the dgv not fitting the screen. 
I have tried setting the properties in the Design Window but it doesn't know what columns it has until the data is loaded.

[dgv properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZZzy.png)

I have also tried code snippets like this:

```
dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 1;
dataGridView1.Columns[1].Width = 1;
dataGridView1.Columns[3].Width = 1;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: First load the data into the DataGridView. Then set the properties of the columns.

Comment: Set the properties in code? Or in the design window?

Comment: Column properties cannot be set in design mode because there are no columns yet. Of course set in the code. **After** loading (binding) data.

Comment: Thats what I did when I tried 'DataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 1;'